# Component Visibility Filter Added after Profile Change

Tags: lightning-web-components, visibility, user-profile, system

Had some unusual behavior today. We were modifying profiles in the Sandbox, and I removed the `View All Data` in the System Permissions of our Sales Agents `profiles`. After doing this, one of our custom `LightningWebComponents` on the `Opportunity Page` suddenly had a filter on the component to effect the visibility based on: IF user viewing it was a manager profile and system admin profile, then show component.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Does anyone know what causes it?

Comment: do you think you could reproduce the steps in a different sandbox and get the same change in visibility?

Comment: I just exported our profiles from production, and reset the profiles. I'm going to try to reproduce tomorrow. I think it has something to do with the view setup system permission.